# Android Facebook java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to use the facebook sdk for use the login. I linked my project with the folder FaceBook SDK, and I checked on the properties in my project 'Android Private Libraries', and 'Android Dependencies'.

But when I launch my app', I have this error :

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
```

I checked, and i've android.support.v'.jar in my libs..

I don't understand where is the problem..

Comment: https://plus.google.com/photos/+AndreasSt%C3%BCtz/albums/5878509263473846433/5878509268379848162?pid=5878509268379848162&oid=%2BAndreasSt%C3%BCtz

Comment: lol.. please read what i wrote.

Comment: Ah! My Bad. Apologies.

Comment: do you add your 'Android Private Libraries correctly ??

Comment: i think yes... i created again the project, and now, it's "working", i've an other error... a fatal exception AsyncTask.